# Obtain string path in Filechooser

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, save, jfilechooser

I have a text editor program that opens up a file chooser whenever you click on Save in a Menu.

In order to achieve this saving process I create a file and save it with the current path in the file chooser.

```
// jfc = JFileChooser
String path = jfc.getSelectedFile().toString();
File testFile = new File(path);
```

This seems to work when I select an existing file in the file chooser, I.E `"bio.txt"` gets saved as a String in my program with the path `"C:/Rikard/bio.txt"`

But whenever I type in a new file name in the File name section and click Save, it doesn't save as a `String` and i get a `NullPointerException`, for Example `Rikard.txt`. It says in the method description that `getSelectedFile()` gets the file from user input by typing.

What could be wrong with my code?

[image]

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) for a working example.

Comment: 1) `String path = jfc.getSelectedFile().toString(); File testFile = new File(path);` could be shortened to `File testFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();` 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: .. 3) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)